# Java- Print the source code of imported class

Tags: java, class, jakarta-ee

Is there any way to view the source code of the imported class?
For example

```
import java.io.Reader;
public class Helper {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        // print source code of java.io.Reader
    }
}
```

How can I print the source code of `java.io.Reader` in my class?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I simply want to print the content of class file. @ScaryWombat

Comment: But why?  Seriously curious

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to print the source code of imported class.

Yes you can view the source code of imported class. In your case source code for `Reader` can be found in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\src.zip\java\io\Reader.java` or the path where JDK is installed in your system.

Any `.class` file can be de-compiled to generate the source code but that will not guarantee to the exact source code.

Comment: @TweetMan does this help?